# Missing "Android SQLite" items in IntelliJ IDEA database plugin

Tags: android, sqlite, intellij-idea

I want to access SQLite in Android device by IntelliJ database plugin.

[Referenced document: "Accessing Android SQLite Databases from IntelliJ IDEA"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/accessing-android-sqllite-databases-from-product.html)

> 2. Click `+` on the toolbar and select Android SQLite from the drop-down menu.

However, missing "Android SQLite" items in drop-down menu.
How do I connect to SQLite database of Android devices?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwfIS.png)

IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate version 2018.2

Answer (score 0):

It is available in Android projects only by opening Android projects in IntelliJ. Make sure the Android Support plugin is enabled.